# MySQL Optimized data storage in database, when entry was changed

Tags: php, mysql, database, optimization

We faced with a problem:

When we are generating accounts (or other documents), we use customer (employee) data. 
However, customers can change their data (e.g. woman get married and her last name changed, or she moved
to live in other country and her address changed).

We need, that after editing woman last name, accounts 
remain with old last name until specific date,and after that specific date, use woman new last name.

e.g. We have a woman: Emily Smith. She married 2014 December 15, and her last name become Brown. 
Before: December 15 we generate her account with Smith last name but after December 15
we need to generate her account with Brown last name. So in database we need to save both her last names.

How to save entry optimized with only one or a few changed attributes?

P.S. We also need to save the date when the change was made in order to know which last name to use, old or new.

Comment: Please, make your question readable, and read about [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sounds like you know what the requirements are, have you tried coding for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a slowly changing dimensions.  The traditional approach is to have records with an effective date and end date attached.  So, Emily would have two rows in this table:

```
AccountId    Firstname     LastName     EffDate      EndDate
   1           Emily       Smith        2001-01-01   2014-12-14
   1           Emily       Brown        2014-12-15   NULL
```

Often, the `NULL` value for the current record would be some arbitrary date far in the future (such as 9999-12-31).  Not having to deal with `NULL`s in the logic can improve perfromance.

Then, when you want the record as of a particular date, you just use the record that is valid on that date.  If you want the current record, the same logic holds -- find the record valid today.

Comment: And to avoid duplicate entries on selects you can query them from a view made upon select for current date.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, your answer is good and it's right for us. We really appreciate it.

Comment: @Arturas if the answer helped you and you are full of appreciation, then what we do on SO is upvote and accept the answer. Gordon took the time to understand and resolve you problem, pay the man back for his time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon has a good start on this, but the truth is that the complexity comes in when you write the joins that use a scheme like this.

To use his scheme, you need to write queries that look like this:

```
SELECT s.*, n.firstname, n.lastname FROM sometable AS s INNER JOIN account_names AS n ON s.accountid = n.accountid AND CURRENT_DATE() BETWEEN n.effdate AND n.endate
```

You can alternatively add a column to account_names like account_name_id, and actually link all of the subordinate records to it if you don't want to do date comparisons all the time.  In that case, sometable would need to have an account_name_id instead of an account_id.